Separators in gs1 barcode
I am trying to add custom separators for creating the GS1 using python-barcode, but after adding them, I can't read the barcode with the scanner.
I have been testing Ê, \x1D, u'\xf1', b'\x1D', \x1d, \xe8 but none of them have worked so far.
Do you have any ideas to solve this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Perhaps, this module may be help you. Why not check out some information on it? odoo-addon-base-gs1-barcode - PyPI
